# React Native Stack Maintained React Navigation

Tags: react-native

I want to see the list of stack maintained by React Native. But, I didn't get it anywhere that how can I.

I use this.props.navigation but it gives the current limited information of current stack. I want to see all the stack maintained by React Native.

Thanks

Comment: I also don't know it, but can you please share your problem , like where you stuck or why you need it?

Comment: I am facing a complex type of problem due to pagination and React Native Navigation. Drawer having the categories list on click they are all going to the screen CategoryList.
Problem Statement:

When I click randomly on categories every thing is working fine. But, getting the problem during pagination. Suppose I click on category Consumer and scroll for more records. After that I click on Mobile category. Mobile Category Page will be shown for a second and after that previous route is called (Consumer).

Comment: in my case I have a scenario like guest, logged in user, uploading ... I have handled it by using different different stacks,

Comment: like guest functionality has its own stack and logged in has its own.

Comment: Yes they are having the different stacks.

Comment: Actually in simple terms what happened that when I click on Cat A page is listed. I scroll down for other records.
After that I click on category C. Page start loading suddenly it redirected to the previous route and showing the products of Cat A instead of B.
But, it is working fine if I clicked on categories and do not load more products.

Comment: replace method of navigation will help you I think !

Comment: Replace is working. But, you know the previous route from stack is deleted. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205415/discussion-between-tushar-pandey-and-vikas-dhiman).

Comment: sorry i think I have to explore it....